# Asynchronous Data loading but UI becomes Unresponsive WPF

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, multithreading, entity-framework

I have a `window` that has a `StackPanel` named as `ControlContainer` . I am loading a `UserControl` in this `StackPanel` on button click event using this code .

```
private void ManageInvoicesFunc(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{    
  ControlContainer.Children.Clear();
   if (sender == null)
    {
      throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(sender));
    }
  UserControl newControl = new ManageInvoiceControl();
  ControlContainer.Children.Add(newControl);
}
```

This `UserControl` has a `DataGrid` named as `InvoiceGrid` and i am loading Data into this `DataGrid` on a Button Click Event, using this code.

```
private async void FetchInvoicesDataFunc(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
   ProgressBtn.Content = "Loading Data ...";
   InvoiceGrid.ItemsSource = await  FetchInvoiceDataAsync();
   ProgressBtn.Content = "Loaded !";
 }

private async Task<List<Invoice>> FetchInvoiceDataAsync()
 {
   List<Invoice> result;
   using(var context = new Intelliventory_DBEntities() )
 {   
   result  = await context.Invoices.Where(b => b.InvoiceID <= 100).Include(x => x.Customer).ToListAsync();
        }
   return  result;
 }
```

I am using `Entity Framework`. The code that is fetching data from database looks Asynchronous . But still i am facing this problem . When The button is clicked and `ManageInvoicesFunc` is called The UI become Unresponsive for a sec or more. Then it becomes normal but then again when the data in `DataGrid` is about to load, the UI become Unresponsive again. and finally when the data is loaded, The UI is Kinda Responsive but the `DataGrid` is Kinda unresponsive that causes UI to become Unresponsive . I am loading only 100 records.
Please help me what's the problem in code or UI design ?
**Data I am Loading**
[image: dataGrid]

Comment: I have actually tried it before ! and the problem is still same . The UI become Unresponsive when data is about to load and when loaded when hover over Grid the UI becomes Unresponsive

Comment: i was doing both together but then  changed it to see if it work taht way ! but it's same . Button in main WINDOW loads UserControl that has DataGrid . Then a Button in UserControl call this event to load data into datagrid and then UI becomes Unresponsive ! and when data is loaded if i hover over DataGrid the whole Ui hangs and become kinda unresponsive!

Comment: i have already shown that ! the first `ManageInvoicesFunc` code that i have mentioned loads `UserControl` that has this `DataGrid` and `Button` that  loads Data into DataGrid, into `StackPanel` of `Window`.

Comment: `FetchInvoicesDataFunc` is called when button is clicked ! that is Async code

Comment: Do not use a `StackPanel`. It disables the UI virtualization of the `DataGrid`. Replace it with a `Grid` or a `DockPanel`.

Comment: i replaced it with Grid still same !

Comment: and i have enabled the virtualization for rows and columns in DataGrid

Comment: @mm8 please resolve this issue ! i know you ca ..no one has yet resolved it !Please already wasted one night and this day !

Comment: Is the UI still unresponsive *after* the data has been loaded into the `DataGrid`?

Comment: and let me tell you ! problem is with Grid because if i don't show Data into DataGrid UI remains Responsive ! but when i assign `DataGrid.ItemSource` it becomes unresponsive!

Comment: About How many rows are being returned from your query?  The actual adding of rows from changing the `ItemsSource` still takes place on the UI thread.  If there are a LOT of rows, it could slow things down.

Comment: i am loading 100 rows now ! but number of rows will be more later ! @BradleyUffner

Comment: Yes when Hover Over the Grid the UI becomes unresponsive and hangs ! @mm8

Comment: Can you use a live inspector on the grid to make sure that it is *actually* still virtualizing?  There are many subtle things that can cause a control to stop virtualizing when you think it should be.

Comment: @BradleyUffner don't know how to do that ..but A Grid>Grid>UserControl>DataGrid while Virtualization is enabled . this is flow of design ! i think Virtualization is enabled Fine !

Comment: Do any of your DB calls use lazy loading?  When the grid probes the columns, it might be triggering a lazy load, which causes it it hit the database again.

Comment: Important point i am using Material Design in Xaml Toolkit ! can this be a problem ?

Comment: @BradleyUffner Not sure but obviously doing EagerLoading ! as you can see in the code ! but as i mentioned Fetch from database is Fine if i dont assign it to DataGrid .but setting DataGrid.itemSource makes it unresponsive when datagrid loads data !

Comment: **The problem is Resolved** ! the DataGrid was inside a StackPanel :( BUT still increasing the number of rows to 1000 makes UI go hang again ! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to help others ! Problem is not with this Asynchronous code but the DataGrid itself. `DataGrid` was inside a Stack Panel that made `Virtualization` disabled. Plus `DataGrid` should have defined height and should not be inside a `ScrollView` and it will work fine !